# ¿Como eliminar Profesor y Alumno con Classroom API?

Tags: eliminar

Necesito borrar alumnos y profesores agregados a una clase en Google Classroom, mediante API.

Al momento de intentar borrar un alumno o docente de una clase, se genera los siguientes errores:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.students.delete failed with error: Requested entity was not found.
(anónimo)   @ Código.gs:254
eliminarEstudiante  @ Código.gs:252

El codigo completo es el siguiente, allí se llaman las clases ya creadas en un documento de Google Sheet y desde allí se ingresa el correo se selecciona la funcion a realizar para ejecutar el codigo, pero solo la parte de EliminarEstudiantes y EliminarProfesor, me genera error como si no encontrara el correo a eliminar.
Según la documentación de GOOGLE debe ser delete y no remove, pero con delete me dice que la función no existe.
Adjunto algunas imagenes, del proceso seleccionando desde el excel y luego la ejecución en AppScript

```
//-------------------------------------CLASSROOM----------------------------------
const NOMBRE = 0;
const GRUPO = 1;
const PROFESOR = 2;
const TITULAR_CORREO=3;
const SECCION =4;
const DESCRIPTION=5;
const AULA = 6;
const CURSO_ID=7;
const CORREO=4;
const ID_CLASE=0;


const sheetGestionDeClassrooms = SS.getSheetByName('Gestion Classrooms');
var clasesGestion = sheetGestionDeClassrooms.getDataRange().getValues();
clasesGestion.shift();
clasesGestion.shift();

//crea un classroom
function createCourses() {
  var sheetMaterias = SS.getSheetByName('Materias');
  var materias = sheetMaterias.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  materias.shift();
  materias.shift();
  materias.forEach((materia, fila)=>{
    var courseSettings={
      name: materia[NOMBRE],
      section: materia [SECCION],
      ownerId: 'me',
      courseState: 'ACTIVE'
    }
    var grupo = materia[GRUPO];
    console.log(grupo);
    try{
      //Creo la clase
      var course = Classroom.Courses.create(courseSettings);
      var courseId = course.id;
      
      //muestro id en la tabla Materias
      sheetMaterias.getRange(fila+3,CURSO_ID+1).setValue(courseId);
      //invito profe
      Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create({userId: materia[TITULAR_CORREO]}, courseId);
      //invito estudiantes
      listGroupMembers(grupo, courseId);
      
    } catch (err) {
      
      Logger.log('Fallo la creacion de la clase. Error message: %s', err.message);
    }
  });
}

function listGroupMembers(group, courseId) {
  try{
  //listo los miembros del grupo y los agrego uno por uno en la clase
  var users = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group).members;
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var email = user.email;
    console.log(user.email);
    if(user.email!="sistemas@colegiofrancia.edu.mx"){
      Classroom.Courses.Students.create({"userId": email},courseId);
    }
  }
  } catch (err) {
      
      Logger.log('Fallo la creacion de la clase. Error message: %s', err.message);
    }
  
}

function agregarEstudiante(){
  clasesGestion.forEach(clase=>{
    if(clase[5] == true){
      Classroom.Courses.Students.create({"userId": clase[CORREO]},clase[ID_CLASE]);
    }
  });
}

function agregarProfesor(){
  clasesGestion.forEach(clase=>{
    if(clase[6] == true){
      console.log (clase[CORREO]);
      Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create({"userId": clase[CORREO]},clase[ID_CLASE]);
    }
  });

}

function obtenerClases(){

  if(sheetGestionDeClassrooms.getLastRow() >= 3){
      sheetGestionDeClassrooms.getRange(3,1,sheetGestionDeClassrooms.getLastRow() -1, 9).clearContent();
  }

  var argumentos = {
    "courseStates": ["ACTIVE"]
  }
  var listaClases = [];

  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(argumentos);
  var clasesConsola = response.courses;
  clasesConsola.forEach( clasesConsola =>{
    var courseId = clasesConsola.id;
    var nombre = clasesConsola.name;
    var seccion = clasesConsola.section;
    var estado= clasesConsola.courseState;
    listaClases.push([courseId, nombre, seccion, estado]);
  });
  sheetGestionDeClassrooms.getRange(3,1,listaClases.length,listaClases[0].length).setValues(listaClases);
}

  function eliminarEstudiante(){
    clasesGestion.forEach(clase=>{
      if(clase[7] == true){
        Classroom.Courses.Students.remove({"userId": clase[CORREO]},clase[ID_CLASE]);
      }
    });
  }

  function eliminarProfesor(){
    clasesGestion.forEach(clase=>{
      if(clase[8] == true){
        Classroom.Courses.Teachers.remove({"userId": clase[ID_CLASE]}, clase[CORREO]);
      }
    });
  }

function coursePatch() {
  clasesGestion.forEach(clase=>{
    var claseId = clase[ID_CLASE];
    let course = {
      'courseState': 'ARCHIVED'
    };
    const mask = {
      updateMask: 'courseState'
    };
    try {
      if(clase[9]== true){
        // Update section and room in course.
        course = Classroom.Courses.patch(body=course, id=claseId, updateMask=mask);
        Logger.log('Course "%s" updated.', course.name);
        obtenerClases();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // TODO (developer) - Handle Courses.patch() exception
      Logger.log('Failed to update the course. Error message: %s', err.message);
    }
  })
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomendaría editar la pregunta para que puedas ordenar bien tu problema, esta muy confuso.

Comment: Hola user326720, bienvenido, a tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y obtengas una mejor respuesta, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.